# Owin not authenticated when requesting access token

Tags: owin, identityserver4

I'm using implicit grant type, and when I request "id_token token" as response type my HttpContext.Current.User is null after logging in leading me to believe something has gone wrong inside owin. If I just have "id_token" as response type its fine. Do I need to tell owin somewhere to get the access token?

For reference I'm using .Net Framework as my client and identityserver4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get the token via browser you need to set `AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true` on client's config within IdentityServer:

```
                new Client
                {
                    ...

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    ...
                },
```

and on MVC client's Startup, to you can add the `access_token` as a claim to user:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ...
                ResponseType = "id_token token",             

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
                        
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I have the full working sample [here](https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/master/src/Net4MvcClient/Startup.cs)

Comment: Awesome thank you! As a follow up, how would I use this access token to talk to a local API in identity server?

Comment: just get the access_token and set it in request header when calling api. Here is an example https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L50. only difference is that in your case you get the access_token from user's claims. Local API in IDS4 is like any other API

Comment: Nevermind - figured it out. If anyone else is wondering this worked for me:

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/api/Users/TestMethod"); client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenHelper.GetAccessToken());

Then just continue with a usual http request. FYI the tokenHelper just gets me the value of the access_token claim. Thanks again nahidf for your help!

Comment: @Josh np, happy could help, feel free to read my blog about it https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/#call-an-authorized-api-endpoint-using-access-token